# Reading JSON file in Python - doesn't look to be in standard format - how to parse it?

Tags: python, json

I don't think this is in the standard `json` format. I don't see the colons that I've seen in other examples. For example, you can see the first line shows Florida (FL). So I would have thought I would see something like 'State':'FL'. The headers aren't shown here but when I look at the web page results the headers are shown. Are the colons required in order to parse this effectively? Ultimately I'd like to get this into CSV format so that I can load it into Excel. The below is a sample of the file.

```
{  
   'aaData':[  
      [  
         [  
            '99.04,99.08,99.08,99.12,99.08,99.11,99.12,99.13,99.11,99.11,99.12,99.13,99.11,99.10,99.09,99.06,99.09,99.11,99.09,99.13,99.11,99.07,98.96,98.38,98.66,99.11,99.10,98.70',
            '2961916',
            '4'
         ],
         '**FL**',
         'Atmore',
         'WALNUT HILL',
         'JAKES ROAD',
         'WLHLFL',
         'EquipmentType',
         '.',
         '1-1-2-1',
         '.',
         '2015-09-10',
         '2015-10-07',
         None,
         '6.14',
         '99.13',
         '908',
         '345',
         '448',
         '971',
         '24.00',
         '2672',
         '0',
         '0',
         '0',
         'Critical',
         '2672',
         '2015-10-09 12:57:50'
      ],
      [  
         [  
            '98.31,98.06,97.55,96.10,97.62,98.20,97.18,97.26,97.74,96.94,97.61,98.03,98.66,97.69,98.17,97.61,98.23,96.98,97.97,97.84,97.62,98.16,97.05,98.05,98.11,97.40,96.72,95.87',
            '3133016',
            '4'
         ],
         'FL',
         'Atmore',
         'MOLINO',
         'QUINTETTE',
         'MOLNFL',
         'EquipmentType',
         '.',
         '1-1-2-1',
         '.',
         '2015-09-10',
         '2015-10-07',
         None,
         '3.07',
         '98.66',
         '1017',
         '338',
         '416',
         '916',
         '31.39',
         '2687',
         '0',
         '0',
         '0',
         'Critical',
         '2687',
         2015-10         -09         12:57:50
      ]
   ]
```

Current Code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url_fl = 'http://corporate.server.private/server/scripts/other /get_json_bw_report.php?tType=Port&sList=&bList=%274%27,%273%27,%272%27,%271%27&stList=%27FL%27'

str_response = urlopen(url_fl).read().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(str_response)
print(obj)
```

EDIT

Adding this code gets me to the data I want to extract:

```
list1 = obj['aaData'][0][1:]
print(list1)

list2 = obj['aaData'][1][1:]
print(list2)

list3 = obj['aaData'][2][1:]
print(list3)
```

Result:

```
['FL', 'Atmore', 'WALNUT HILL', 'JAKES ROAD', 'WLHLFL', 'EquipmentType', '.', '1-1-2-1', '.', '2015-09-11', '2015-10-08', None, '6.14', '99.13', '916', '357', '430', '969', '24.00', '2672', '0', '0', '0', 'Critical', '2672', '2015-10-10 09:02:28']
['FL', 'Atmore', 'MOLINO', 'QUINTETTE', 'MOLNFL', 'EquipmentType', '.', '1-1-2-1', '.', '2015-09-11', '2015-10-08', None, '3.07', '98.66', '1027', '341', '412', '907', '31.39', '2687', '0', '0', '0', 'Critical', '2687', '2015-10-10 09:02:28']
['FL', 'Atmore', 'WALNUT HILL', 'BAY SPRINGS', 'WLHLFL', 'EquipmentType', '.', '1-1-2-1', '.', '2015-09-11', '2015-10-08', None, '6.14', '99.13', '1062', '428', '438', '760', '31.53', '2688', '0', '0', '0', 'Critical', '2688', '2015-10-10 09:02:28']
```

But these needs to iterate through the file and find each instance. The pattern is `['aaData'][0][1:]`, `['aaData'][1][1:]`, `['aaData'][2][1:]`. The file can have many like this. How can I iterate or loop through the file and print each of these?

EDIT - final code that works

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import csv

url_fl = 'http://company.server.org'

url_response = urlopen(url_fl).read().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(url_response)
obj_parse = obj['aaData']

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    data = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for row in obj_parse:
        data.writerows([row[1:]])
```

Comment: Where did you obtain that file from?

Comment: Do you get an exception when you run your code? Colons are only required where they belong; your data has arrays and array notation does not contain a colon in it.

Comment: This has a colon. There is one name `aadata` and a nested arrays as the value portion of that name/value pair.

Comment: I inspected the web page and obtain the URL. On the web page you select region, state etc and click search. The results show up on the web page with columns. I have to do this for numerous states and exchanges.

Comment: @David Zemens - yep it has the colon at the very beginning but I thought there would colons separating the headers from the actual data. For example, something like 'state:fl', 'exchange:molino'.

Comment: @dsh I do not get an exception. When I run that code I get the results as shown in my original post. Although it doesn't have any breaks in it. It's all on one line.

Comment: @DavidZemens - That one name aadata is the only name no matter how large the results are. For example, if I select multiple states that name always comes at the beginning. Followed by three opening [[[. Do I just need to go with split() method to format this how I want it in order to get it into a format that would work as a CSV file?

Comment: @shavar I thought that was the input you were showing, not the output of your code.  The answer, then, is that you read the JSON correctly. The JSON is standard, it is valid, and you parsed it. You just need to process the data structure now. Just a note: JSON does not have headers. I recommend researching what JSON actually is to better understand it.  As another note, most likely the web site you obtained this from is using [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/) based on the presence of the `aaData` attribute of the returned object.

Comment: @shavar No, you don't want to use `string.split()` at all. You have correctly parsed the JSON. The data structure is a dict with one entry (shown in your excerpt), the value of that is a list of records each of which are a list of data (probably corresponding to the columns in the table on the web page).

Comment: @dsh Ok I think I understand JSON a little better after some reading (http://json.org/). It looks like each line is made up of two arrays with elements separated by commas. So my terminology was off...rather then parsing I'm looking to now process the data. What's the best method to process the data? I just need some pointers or suggestions to get me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import csv

url_fl = 'http://company.server.org'

url_response = urlopen(url_fl).read().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(url_response)
obj_parse = obj['aaData']

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    data = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for row in obj_parse:
        data.writerows([row[1:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have realized by now, the JSON is correct and you correctly parsed it in Python.  Now you have a data structure to process.

In Python, you can process a list using a `for` loop:

```
for row in obj['aaData']:
    print( row[1:] )
```

You'll want to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) module to encode the data structure you produce (namely the list of data you want in your file) correctly according to the CSV respresentation.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up. I actually did figure how to iterate over the object to extract just the [1:]. I was able to write this to a file as well. Of course everything printed to the first line. Your mention of the csv module got me to the latest edit. Please see the code I'm at now. This almost works. If I remove the [1:] portion from the last line it prints out the JSON data on a separate line but includes the first [0:] which I don't want. With [1:] it clears the file content (no error).

Comment: I got it. It's data.writerows([row[1:]]). Thanks for your help.